# java com.microsoft.sqlserver exception

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I have developed a java website in jsf technology. In order to fullfil some tasks i need to connect and retriece data from an MS SQLServer 2008.

The application works perfeclty, at least i think, but when it is tie mto redeploy my site because of a cange i always get an error of type

> The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ActivityCorrelator$1] and a value of type [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ActivityId]  but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

In order to connect to DB i use the below code:

```
Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement prepSQL = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        UserInfo userDetails = null;

        try
        {
            //Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            String DBuserName = "myusername";
            String DBpassword = "mypassword";
            String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433"+";databaseName=myDB";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, DBuserName, DBpassword);

            String query = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Users where Username= ? ";
            prepSQL  = con.prepareStatement(query);
            prepSQL.setString(1, username);
            rs = prepSQL.executeQuery();

            String[] result = new String[8];

            if(rs!=null){
                while (rs.next()){
                    if (EncryptDecrypt.decrypt(rs.getString("Password")).equals(password))
                    {
                        userDetails = new UserInfo();
                        userDetails.setID(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("ID")));
                        userDetails.setUsername(rs.getString("Username"));
                        userDetails.setFirstName(rs.getString("FirstName"));
                        userDetails.setSurname(rs.getString("Surname"));
                        userDetails.setRole(rs.getString("Role"));
                    }
                    else
                        userDetails = null;
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            userDetails = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (rs!=null)
                rs.close();
            if (prepSQL!=null)
                prepSQL.close();
            if (con!=null)
                con.close();
        }
```

I can't understand what i am doing wrong and i get this error as i close my connection every time

Comment: I have the EXACT same problem with SQL2012.  Did you fix this?  I have an older war(mere eleven days ago) that deploys perfectly and no changes to the core db connectivity.

Comment: For my case it was a simple file size issue, see[link](https://tecadmin.net/increase-tomcat-upload-file-size-limit/)